Why didn't the same result as the main query come after merging with Union using PostgreSQL?
main query:

select 
  * 
from 
  (
    select 
      c.register_no, 
      C.name, 
      T.name taxoffice, 
      C.tax_no, 
      (
        select 
          first_name || ' ' || last_name 
        from 
          "user" 
        where 
          id in (
            select 
              COALESCE(
                customer_representative_id, sales_representative_id
              ) 
            from 
              customer_representative 
            where 
              company_id = C.id 
            order by 
              id desc 
            limit 
              1
          )
      ) cus_rep, 
      coalesce(Cr.code, null) currency, 
      sum(debit) total, 
      (
        sum(debit) - sum(balance_debit)
      ) paid, 
      (
        sum(balance_debit)
      ) balance, 
      (
        SELECT 
          ROUND(
            CAST(
              COALESCE(
                SUM(TOPLAM)/ SUM(credit), 
                0
              ) AS INTEGER
            ), 
            2
          ) performance 
        FROM 
          (
            SELECT 
              DATE_PART(
                'day', 
                CAST(B.create_date AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST(A.document_date AS TIMESTAMP)
              ) * B.credit AS TOPLAM, 
              B.credit 
            FROM 
              ledger_entry A 
              INNER JOIN matched_invoice B on B.ledger_entry_id = A.id 
            WHERE 
              (
                A.due_date <= '2024-03-25' 
                and (
                  COALESCE(A.credit, 0)> 0
                ) 
                and A.firm_id = 123078 
                and A.document_date >= '2024-03-25'
              )
          ) foo
      ), 
      sum(
        case when Le.due_date > '2024-03-25' then balance_debit end
      ) unexpired, 
      (
        select 
          COALESCE(
            sum(balance_debit), 
            0
          ) 
        from 
          ledger_entry L 
        where 
          L.entity_id not in (
            select 
              id 
            from 
              invoice 
            where 
              id = L.entity_id 
              and is_exchange_difference = true
          ) 
          and L.company_id = C.id 
          and L.currency_id = Cr.id 
          and L.currency_id = Le.currency_id 
          and due_date >= '2024-03-26' 
          and due_date <= '2024-04-01'
      ) P0, 
      (
        select 
          COALESCE(
            sum(balance_debit), 
            0
          ) 
        from 
          ledger_entry L 
        where 
          L.entity_id not in (
            select 
              id 
            from 
              invoice 
            where 
              id = L.entity_id 
              and is_exchange_difference = true
          ) 
          and L.company_id = C.id 
          and L.currency_id = Cr.id 
          and L.currency_id = Le.currency_id 
          and due_date >= '2024-04-02' 
          and due_date <= '2024-04-08'
      ) P1, 
      1 s 
    from 
      ledger_entry Le, 
      Company C 
      left join tax_office T on C.tax_office_id = T.id, 
      Currency Cr 
    where 
      (
        Le.entity_id is null 
        or Le.entity_id not in (
          select 
            id 
          from 
            invoice 
          where 
            id = Le.entity_id 
            and is_exchange_difference = true
        )
      ) 
      and Le.company_id = C.id 
      and Le.currency_id = Cr.id 
      and Le.debit <> 0 
      and Le.firm_id = 123078 
    group by 
      c.register_no, 
      C.name, 
      T.name, 
      C.tax_no, 
      Cr.code, 
      Le.currency_id, 
      c.id, 
      cr.id
  ) foo 
where 
  balance <> 0 
  and balance >=-1.0E9 
  and balance <= 1.0E9 
order by 
  s

My main purpose here is that there is an optimization problem in the main query and to solve it.
I broke the query into parts
The point I need to pay attention to when taking it apart is
In the main query, the group by sections would be combined like a table with union.
My goals is for the results of the union query and the main query to be the same, but the results are not the same.
And the parts I bought in union are:
total or total is used in the same sense
TOTAL,
paid,
balance,
performance,
unexpired,
P0,
P1
for example like here
  select a,b
  from ledger_entry
  UNION
  select c,d
  from ledger_entry
  UNION
  select 0,0,0,0
  from currency x
  group by a, b,c,d,x,


Below is my union query


 -- Parça 1
    SELECT
        0 AS TOPLAM,
        0 AS paid,
        0 AS balance,
        0 AS performance,
        0 AS unexpired,
        CASE
            WHEN L.due_date >= '2024-03-26' AND L.due_date <= '2024-04-01' THEN COALESCE(L.balance_debit, 0)
            ELSE 0
        END AS P0,
        CASE
            WHEN L.due_date >= '2024-04-02' AND L.due_date <= '2024-04-08' THEN COALESCE(L.balance_debit, 0)
            ELSE 0
        END AS P1
    FROM 
        ledger_entry L
    LEFT JOIN 
        company C ON C.id = L.company_id
    WHERE   
        L.company_id = C.id   
        AND L.firm_id = 123078  
        AND entity_id NOT IN (
            SELECT id 
            FROM invoice 
            WHERE id = entity_id 
            AND is_exchange_difference = true
        )
    
    UNION
    
    -- Parça 2
    SELECT
        DATE_PART('day', CAST(M.create_date AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST(L.document_date AS TIMESTAMP)) * M.credit AS TOPLAM,
        (L.debit - L.balance_debit) AS paid,
        L.balance_debit AS balance,
        CASE 
            WHEN M.id IS NOT NULL THEN (
                SELECT ROUND(CAST(COALESCE(SUM(TOPLAM) / SUM(credit), 0) AS INTEGER), 2) 
                FROM (
                    SELECT DATE_PART('day', CAST(B.create_date AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST(A.document_date AS TIMESTAMP)) * B.credit AS TOPLAM,
                    B.credit 
                    FROM ledger_entry A 
                    INNER JOIN matched_invoice B ON B.ledger_entry_id = A.id 
                    WHERE (A.due_date <= '2024-03-25' AND (COALESCE(A.credit, 0) > 0) AND A.firm_id = 123078 AND A.document_date >= '2024-03-25')
                ) foo
            ) 
        END AS performance,
        CASE 
            WHEN M.id IS NOT NULL AND L.due_date > '2024-03-25' THEN balance_debit 
        END AS unexpired,
        0 AS P0,
        0 AS P1
    FROM 
        ledger_entry L
    LEFT JOIN 
        matched_invoice M ON M.ledger_entry_id = L.id
    WHERE 
        L.due_date >= '2024-03-25' 
        AND L.firm_id = 123078
    
    UNION
    
    -- Parça 3
    SELECT 
        0 AS TOPLAM,
        0 AS paid,
        0 AS balance,
        0 AS performance,
        0 AS unexpired,
        0 AS P0,
        0 AS P1
    FROM 
        currency cr
    
    UNION
    
    -- Parça 4
    SELECT 
        0 AS TOPLAM,
        0 AS paid,
        0 AS balance,
        0 AS performance,
        0 AS unexpired,
        0 AS P0,
        0 AS P1
    FROM 
        tax_office t

UNION

-- Parça 5
SELECT 
    0 AS TOPLAM,
    0 AS paid,
    0 AS balance,
    0 AS performance,
    0 AS unexpired,
    0 AS P0,
    0 AS P1
FROM 
    Company C


try union all, a simple union makes an implicit distinct

I tried but it gave the same error result with union all.

Can you provide us with  your expected output and  output/error you are getting?

I corrected the logic of the problem again and made new improvements, but the union query still does not give results like the main query.
